# Simplify this MySQL select - I'd really want concat_ws to produce null

Tags: mysql

This gives the required output but it is very ugly

```sql
select if(concat_ws('~', x, y) = '', null, concat_ws('~', x, y));
```

if x & y are `null` then I want `null` returned, but it gives `''`, plain concat does this, but I want the separator (when x, y are not `null`)

I tried using variables, but it seems they are not set early enough to reuse in the same select.
I'm tied to a framework so I really can't do too much, it needs to be all done in a single select field, like above.

Comment: @JNevill, that should probably be an Answer, not a Comment, since you are offering a solution instead of asking for a clarification.

Comment: I'll add as an answer. I feel like it's more of an aside, since it's probably just syntactic sugar and not really an optimization. It's pretty clear from the documentation that `concat_ws` doesn't return `NULL` unless `NULL` is used as the delimter/first-parameter, which is sort of nonsense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your `If()` function to be a `NULLIF()` which is a shortened version of the same logic you are using

```
SELECT NULLIF(concat_ws('~', x, y) , '');
```

I doubt this will bring any optimization to your query besides being easier for us humans to read though. That being said, I believe this is the most concise and optimized that this query will get since `concat_ws` is null-safe by design.